# Switch statement in property C#

Tags: c#

I have created an enum for accessories and used the switch statement in the class property to determine the price depending on the accessories chosen. A class that has two constructors implements this enum, one of the constructors accepts types from this enum as arguments while the other does not. See codes below:

**Expected result**

- If an instance of the class is instantiated with a type of the enum, switch to enum type and return price
- If an instance of the class is instantiated without providing an enum type price should be zero.

**Problem statement**

When an instance is initialized without providing an enum type the switch statement runs and breaks in the first case

```cs
using System;

///<summary>
/// specifies the accessories of a vehicle
///</summary>
public enum Accessories
{
    StereoSystem = 0,
    LeatherInterior = 1,
    StereoAndLeather = 2,
    ComputerNavigation = 3,
    StereoAndNavigation = 4,
    LeatherAndNavigation = 5,
    All = 6,
    None = 7
}

public SalesQuote(decimal vehicleSalePrice, decimal tradeInAmount,
                  decimal salesTaxRate, Accessories accessoriesChosen,
                  ExteriorFinish exteriorFinishChosen)
{
    if (vehicleSalePrice <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("vehicleSalePrice", "The argument cannot" +
            " be less than or equal to zero");
    if (tradeInAmount < 0 || salesTaxRate < 0)
    {
        string myValue = tradeInAmount < 0 ? "tradeInAmount" : "salesTaxRate";
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(myValue, 
            "The argument cannot be less than zero");
    }
    if(salesTaxRate > 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("salesTaxRate",
            "The argument cannot be greater than 1");
    if((!(accessoriesChosen.GetType() == typeof(Accessories) ||!(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Accessories),accessoriesChosen)) )
        ||((!(exteriorFinishChosen.GetType() == typeof(ExteriorFinish)) || !(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ExteriorFinish),exteriorFinishChosen))))))
        throw new System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException
            ("The argument is an invalid enumeration value");

    this.vehicleSalePrice = vehicleSalePrice;
    this.tradeInAmount = tradeInAmount;
    this.salesTaxRate = salesTaxRate;
    this.accessoriesChosen = accessoriesChosen;
    this.exteriorFinishChosen = exteriorFinishChosen;
}

/// Second Constructor

public SalesQuote(decimal vehicleSalePrice, decimal tradeInAmount, decimal salesTaxRate)
{
    if (vehicleSalePrice <= 0 || tradeInAmount < 0)
    {
        string myValue = vehicleSalePrice <= 0 ? "vehicleSalePrice" : "tradeInAmount";
        string completionString = tradeInAmount < 0 ? "0" : "or equal to zero";
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(myValue, "The argument cannot be less than " +
        completionString);
    }
    if (salesTaxRate < 0 || salesTaxRate > 1)
    {
        string completionString = salesTaxRate < 0 ? "less than 0" : "greater than 1";
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("salesTaxRate", "The argument cannot be " +
            completionString);
    }
    this.vehicleSalePrice = vehicleSalePrice;
    this.tradeInAmount = tradeInAmount;
    this.salesTaxRate = salesTaxRate;
}

/// cost property

public decimal AccessoryCost
{
   get 
    {
        decimal accessoryPrice = 0;
        switch (this.AccessoriesChosen)
        {
            case Accessories.StereoSystem:
                accessoryPrice = 505.05m;
                break;
            case Accessories.LeatherInterior:
                accessoryPrice = 1010.10m;
                break;
            case Accessories.ComputerNavigation:
                accessoryPrice = 1515.15m;
                break;
            case Accessories.StereoAndNavigation:
                decimal total = 505.05m + 1515.15m;
                accessoryPrice = total;
                break;
            case Accessories.LeatherAndNavigation:
                total = 1010.10m + 1515.15m;
                accessoryPrice = total;
                break;
            case Accessories.All:
                total = 1010.10m + 1515.15m + 505.05m;
                accessoryPrice = total;
                break;
            default:
                accessoryPrice = 0;
                break;
        }
        return accessoryPrice;
    }
}
```

Initialize with second constructor

```cs
SalesQuote mySalesQuote = new SalesQuote(500,200,.5);
decimal cost = mySalesQuote.AccessoryCost;
/// cost should be zero in this instance since no accessory was selected but I am getting 505.05
```

Please can someone let me know why this is and how to resolve this.

Thanks

I have tried using conditions in the different cases but it appears the type is implicitly casted to the Accessories type which I don't understand why.

```
case Accessories.StereoSystem:
        accessoryPrice = !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Accessories),accessoriesChosen)  ?   0 : 505.05m;
       break;
```

Comment: Did you check what the default value for an `enum` is? Did you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: initialize this.AccessoriesChosen to None in the second constructor. You left it at its default value 0 which is Accessories.StereoSystem

Comment: `None` should always be 0 to make if the default value. Also, you could use a [switch expression (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) which would much shorter in this case.

Comment: Your example code doesn't even compile for me. `.5` needs to be `.5m`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks for the read it makes sense now 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum constants like `None` or `Undefined` should always have the value `0`. This makes them automatically the default value.

Since the enum contains combinations of values, it should be a flags enum

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Accessories
{
    None = 0,
    StereoSystem = 1 << 0,
    LeatherInterior = 1 << 1,
    ComputerNavigation = 1 << 2,

    StereoAndLeather = StereoSystem | LeatherInterior,
    StereoAndNavigation = StereoSystem | ComputerNavigation,
    LeatherAndNavigation = LeatherInterior | ComputerNavigation,
    All = StereoSystem | LeatherInterior | ComputerNavigation
}
```

The unique values are powers of two (1, 2, 4). This allows combining them to form new values and also to test whether a flag is set

```cs
if (accessories.HasFlag(Accessories.StereoSystem)) {

}
```

This simplifies the cost calculation since you don't need to check all the combinations

```cs
public decimal AccessoryCost
{
    get {
        decimal accessoryPrice = 0;
        if (this.AccessoriesChosen.HasFlag(Accessories.StereoSystem)) {
            accessoryPrice += 505.05m;
        }
        if (this.AccessoriesChosen.HasFlag(Accessories.LeatherInterior)) {
            accessoryPrice += 1010.10m;
        }
        if (this.AccessoriesChosen.HasFlag(Accessories.ComputerNavigation)) {
            accessoryPrice += 1515.15m;
        }
        return accessoryPrice;
    }
}
```

E.g., this

```cs
mySalesQuote.AccessoriesChosen = Accessories.StereoAndNavigation;
Console.WriteLine(mySalesQuote.AccessoryCost);
mySalesQuote.AccessoriesChosen = Accessories.All;
Console.WriteLine(mySalesQuote.AccessoryCost);
```

prints

```
2020.20
3030.30
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class design is a bit off. You have 2 different constructors:

```
SalesQuote(decimal vehicleSalePrice, decimal tradeInAmount, decimal salesTaxRate)
```

and

```
SalesQuote(decimal vehicleSalePrice, decimal tradeInAmount,
    decimal salesTaxRate, Accessories accessoriesChosen,
    ExteriorFinish exteriorFinishChosen)
```

It seems that one constructor is a more powerful constructor than the other one. In such a case, you can forward the arguments from the simple constructor to the powerful constructor and provide default arguments.

That way you'll get rid of a lot of duplicate code (which isn't 100% duplicate any more, because they diverged already).

How does it look like?

```cs
public SalesQuote(decimal vehicleSalePrice, decimal tradeInAmount, decimal salesTaxRate)
:this(vehicleSalePrice, tradeInAmount, salesTaxRate, Accessories.None, ExteriorFinish.None)
{

}
```

Notice the `:this()` call. This constructor calls the more powerful constructor.

Also note: since the more powerful constructor needs 5 arguments, you have to provide the default values for the parameters `accessoriesChosen` and `exteriorFinishChosen`.

See how this code sets the default value to `Accessories.None` which fixes your bug.

BTW, you may want to have a look into the Decorator design pattern. Your way of declaring accessories through an enum will not hold for long. More accessories will result in an explosion of combinations. Your code will need more if-statements and break often.